# Show that f is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $a > 0, b \geq 0$ and the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1, & |x| \leq a \\ 
 b & |x| > a
\end{matrix}\right.$$

show that it is measurable.

I don't have clue about to show this!!!

Comment: what's the measure space?

Comment: It wasn't mentioned in exercise but I believe Augustin is right about measurability wrt Borel sigma-algebra :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume measurability with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

You can rewrite $f$ as:
$$f(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[-a,a]}(x)+b\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-a,a]}(x)$$

$[-a,a]$ is an interval so it is measurable. Thus $\mathbb{R}\setminus [-a,a]$ is measurable too. This simplies that the indicator functions $\mathbf{1}_{[-a,a]}$ and $\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}\setminus [-a,a]}$ are measurable functions. You can then conclude by using the fact that the sum and product of measurable functions is still measurable.

Comment: Measurability depends on the measure space?

Comment: Yes it does. As it was not specified, I assumed measurability with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Augustin, do you assume measure is lebesgue measure too?

Comment: We don't need to talk about measures here, as measurability only depends on $E$ (the space itself) and $\mathcal{E}$ (the $\sigma$-algebra).

Comment: The reason an interval is in the Borel sigma-algebra is, um, independent of whether or not Lebesgue measure is being considered? So all that is needed to specify for questions like this is a measurable space (instead of a measure space)?

Comment: Absolutely, all you need is a measurable space. And $[-a,a]$ belongs to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra because by definition, the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets (or closed sets).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Characteristic functions of measurable sets are measurable, so is any linear combination of them. Also when it is not specified euclidean spaces are considered to be equipped with the Borel sigma algebra, which is generated by the collection of open sets.

Comment: Your answer is correct but, to be precise, a measurable function $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ is meant measurable from $(\Bbb R^n,\, \mathcal E)$ to $(\Bbb R,\, \mathcal B)$, where $\mathcal E$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of *Lebesgue-measurable* subsets and $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Functions that are measurable from $(\Bbb R^n,\,\mathcal B)$ to $(\Bbb R,\,\mathcal B)$ are called *Borel functions*. So "euclidean spaces are considered with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra" might be a misleading statement.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli Thanks, good point!

Comment: Measurability depends on the measure space?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's necessarily measurable. Did you mean Lebesgue measurable? If so, then I think so.

---

Let $a, b \in \mathbb R$.

Define $A := \{x | |x| \le a\}$.

Consider a measure space $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$.

$1$ is constant and hence $\Sigma$-measurable. $(**)$

$b$ is constant and hence $\Sigma$-measurable.

If $A \in \Sigma$, then:

1. $1_A$ is $\Sigma$-measurable. $(**)$
2. $A^C \in \Sigma$
3. $1_{A^C}$ is $\Sigma$-measurable.

If $A^C \in \Sigma$, then:

1. $1_{A^C}$ is $\Sigma$-measurable.
2. $A \in \Sigma$
3. $1_{A}$ is $\Sigma$-measurable.

So, if $A \in \Sigma$, then

$$f = 1 \times 1_A + b \times 1_{A^C}$$

since finite sums of $\Sigma-$measurable functions are $\Sigma-$measurable and finite products of $\Sigma-$measurable functions are $\Sigma-$measurable.

If our measure space is $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B(\mathbb R), \lambda)$, then $A \in \mathscr B(\mathbb R)$ because [$A$ is an interval](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=1maVIOLfF7EC&pg=PA111&lpg=PA111&dq=intervals%20are%20lebesgue%20measurable&source=bl&ots=96PT6yttdT&sig=lz_isaiD6BJPymqnOy2dp3h-DjQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ7b_vkfLKAhUUUWMKHQbEArUQ6AEIPTAG#v=onepage&q=intervals%20are%20lebesgue%20measurable&f=false).

---

$(**)$ Note: We say a function $f$ is $\Sigma-$measurable from $(S, \Sigma, \mu)$ to $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B(\mathbb R))$ if

$\sigma(f) := \{f^{-1}(B) | B \in \mathscr B(\mathbb R)\} \subseteq \Sigma$

Now, if $f$ is a constant, then

$\sigma(f) = \{\emptyset, S\} \subseteq \Sigma$

If $f = 1_B$ for $B \in \Sigma$, then

$\sigma(f) = \sigma(B) \subseteq \Sigma \tag{*}$

$(*)$ Note: $B \in \Sigma \to \sigma(B) := \{\emptyset, B, B^C, S\} \subseteq \Sigma$